# i used custom cell table view.in this each cell contain text view and edit button

Tags: iphone, ios4

I assigned custom action for  edit button.

"My query is when i press the edit button it will call the customactionmethod (purpose of this method is to edit the text in textview and store the current values in array).

My requirement is after edited again it will back to didselctrowatindex method.How can i back to didselctrowatindex from customaction method.here is my code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //The user is selecting the cell which is currently expanded
    //we want to minimize it back

    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        selectedIndex = -1;

       [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        return;
    }

    //First we check if a cell is already expanded.

    //If it is we want to minimize make sure it is reloaded to minimize it back
  if(selectedIndex >= 0)
    {

        NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];        

    }

    //Finally set the selected index to the new selection and reload it to expand
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    labelname.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    passionnameslabel.textColor=[UIColor yellowColor];

    textview1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0f];

    textview1.text = [textview1.text stringByAppendingString:[mylifearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    textview1.delegate=self;

    [pes setInteger:selectedIndex forKey:@"selected"];

    [editbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [editbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
}
-(void)customActionPressed
{



    textview1.inputView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];


    textview1.editable=YES;

     mylifearray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[pes objectForKey:@"mylifearray"]];

     [mylifearray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

     [mylifearray insertObject:textview1.text atIndex:selectedIndex];

         [pes setObject:mylifearray forKey:@"mylifearray"];

}
```

Can any body Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please can you try to explain more about what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the delegate method explicitly:

`[self tableView:self.tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Or else, you can also write a method that performs the same action as in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and call it as and when you need.

Comment: thank you for reply sir but i am getting error like 
  error: request for member 'tableView' in something not a structure or union

Comment: Ok, instead of `self.tableView` use the instance of the tableview you have created in your class. You are getting this because you might not have declared your tableview as a property and synthesized it.